# Vagrant fails to mount NFS shared folders because of corrupted /etc/exports. How do I fix that file?

Tags: nfs, vagrant

I recently tried to install a VM with vagrant but "vagrant up" always failed with the error:

> Mounting NFS shared folders failed. This is most often caused by the NFS
>   client software not being installed on the guest machine. Please verify
>   that the NFS client software is properly installed, and consult any resources
>   specific to the linux distro you're using for more information on how to
>   do this.

NFS client was properly installed on my machine so I looked for other causes of errors and found a blogpost explaining that my /etc/exports might be corrupted. I restored exportsbak (which contains only commented examples), hoping that vagrant would reconfigure that file properly... but it doesn't, and the error is still there.

How can I force vagrant to regenerate that file or fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just delete the file.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/exports
```

The file will be recreated during the `vagrant up` process.

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day :D. This did it but I had to recreate the file manually sudo touch /etc/exports

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get nfs running on my Ubuntu, because I used the vagrant packages from apt (V 1.2.2)

I installed the latest Vagrant Version (1.5) from here: http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads
and nfs worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the NSF server is not installed, you can do…

`dpkg -l | grep nfs-kernel-server`

2. If it is not installed, install the required packages…

`apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
apt-get install nfs-common
service nfs-kernel-server restart
sudo service portmap restart
mkdir -p /var/exports`

3. Then in Vagranfile add line under #shared folders...

   config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options =>  "dmode=755","fmode=755"] }

When vagrant is starting it will ask for root password, to run it without root password you can edit /etc/sudoers and add following lines…

```
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD = /usr/bin/tee -a /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK = /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server status

Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_START = /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start

Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY = /usr/sbin/exportfs -ar

Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE = /bin/sed -r -e * d -ibak /etc/exports

%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD, VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK, VAGRANT_NFSD_START, VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE
```

Answer (score 0):

if your host is Windows, then you need to install a vagrant plugin [Vagrant WinNFSd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd).

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

Comment: Why do we need to do this?

Comment: If you follow the link provided, you will find following `Vagrant WinNFSd
Manage and adds support for NFS on Windows.`